# How to split two words using SQL?

Tags: sql

The output should like for example device(a)-to-device(b)_gatewaystats

```
column A         column B
----------------------------
device (a)       device(b)
```

So is there any way to split them as example shown above using SQL

Comment: which db are you using?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What's the condition to split the words?

Comment: Please, describe the rules or at least provide some more input samples and desired output for them